# Product detail pages aren't being indexed because category listing pages have noindex,follow

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I have page with list of products and product details pages. list page must be invisible in google search results and product details must be visible in google search result. I have the following meta tag added to the product list page, but nothing is indexed.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

> Google’s John Mueller said that the ‘noindex,follow’ command in the
>   meta tags of a web page will eventually be interpreted as a
>   ‘noindex,nofollow’ command.
>
> That is not surprising. If Google does not index a page, it cannot
>   follow the links on the page. Here’s John Mueller’s statement:
>
> “It’s tricky with noindex, which I think is something of a
>   misconception in general within the SEO community. With a noindex and
>   follow it’s still the case that we see the noindex. In the first step
>   we say ‘okay you don’t want this page shown in the search results’.
>   We’ll still keep it in our index, we just won’t show it and then we
>   can follow those links.
>
> If we see the noindex there for longer than we think this page really
>   doesn’t want to be used in search so we will remove it completely. And
>   then we won’t follow the links anyway. So noindex and follow is
>   essentially the same as a noindex, nofollow. There’s no really big
>   difference there in the long run.” [see more](https://blog.seoprofiler.com/google-noindexfollow-noindexnofollow-long-run/)

Comment: Do you link your product detail pages together?   If every one of your products links to 10 other products you wouldn't need category pages for SEO linking.

Comment: "That is not surprising. If Google does not index a page, it cannot follow the links on the page."
That does not make sense. Indexing or not indexing a page is not the same as crawling / not crawling a page. I find this is often mixed up, for instance when people make adjustments to the robots.txt, assuming that forbidding to crawl a url in robots.txt that has accidentally been indexed would deindex the page - that is often not the case. It just means the page won't be recrawled.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a sitemap file that lists all your product details pages and submit it to google from the search console.

how to build and submit sitemap to google :
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Comment: An XML sitemap may not help.   They are not usually good at getting pages indexed that wouldn't otherwise be indexed.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Thank you for the link I was not aware. It's very annoying indeed.

Comment: Its worth a shot though.  A sitemap never hurts and they are easy enough to make.